# GoLang multi-tenant application database connections

Tags: database, postgresql, go, multi-tenant

I am new to *golang* and currently trying to build a multi-tenant application. In my application each tenants have their own database. My requirement is that I need to switch database connection per tenant request, how can this be accomplished in *golang*. I prefer *postgresql* for this project.

I can have a map of database connection to tenant, but not sure if this is a good practice.

Your help and suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with having a map of database connections for each tenant? It needs to be mapped somewhere.

Comment: The problem is that suppose we have 1000 tenants we will end up having 1000 database connections open assuming all of them are accessing the application.

Answer (score 1):

I've handled a similar kind of requirement in Rails. Probably you can use the same approach in go-lang also.

I will have one master DB, which will hold just the tenant information. Like tenant name and db_name.

And I've got a rack middleware which will switch DB based on a subdomain(I'm using the subdomain to identify the tenant).

For example, Your master DB can have table `tenants` and an example record might probably look like this:
`{
    id: 1,
    name: 'XYZ',
    db_name: 'xyz'
}`

and when your application receives a request with subdomain `xyz`, Your middleware should switch to `xyz` DB.

Comment: Are all these databases reside in one db clusters? How are you avoiding the reconnection to a database every time a user is sending a request?

Comment: @xxx222 I was wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

its a better solutions to create an schema instead of an entire database and on each request change the schema of the request identifying the tenant.other solutions is to create a database and reopen a connection on each request after the tenant recognition on the middleware